# keep keyboard when searchDisplayControllerWillEndSearch is invoked

Tags: ios, objective-c

With help from other posts on this site, I have managed to open up search display controller with keyboard when a button is tapped. I can see the underlying UIView is dimmed too.

What I now want to do is, not have the keyboard dismissed when the user taps outside the search bar. Currently, the keyboard gets dismissed and searchDisplayControllerWillEndSearch is invoked.

I have tried combinations of the following but none worked.

```
self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.hidden = NO;
[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar setShowsCancelButton:YES animated:YES];
[self.searchDisplayController setActive: YES animated: YES];
[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar becomeFirstResponder]
```

Can anyone please suggest any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't been able to try this, but I think it should work

Declare something as searchbar delegate;

```
@interface YourViewController : UIViewController <UISearchBarDelegate>
```

Then, somewhere in YourViewController.m, set:

```
- (BOOL) searchBarShouldEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    return NO;
}
```

You can set it to return something dynamic, for instance if we only wanted to allow it to stop editing if there isn't any text, we could do this.

```
- (BOOL) searchBarShouldEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    return (searchbar.text.length > 0) ? YES : NO;
}
```

This way, if the user has started typing, or any text is in the search bar, it won't resign.

Let me know if this works.

Comment: It works sort of. When I click on the dimmed area, the keyboard DOES NOT go away, just as I wanted. However the dimmed area is not dimmed anymore and I can see the underlying empty UIView in white color. I wanted the dimmed area to stay dimmed. Or not dimmed at all in the first place. Anyway, now that I have clicked on the dimmed area and see it lose its dimness, when I now go back and search, no search results are shown. It just continues to show the underlying empty UIView in white color.